# Can vtable overhead be avoided using a static_cast?

Tags: c++, vtable, overhead, static-cast

Here is my problem. I have a base class and a derived class which overrides some methods from the base class. For simplicity consider the following example:

```
struct base
{
  virtual void fn()
  {/*base definition here*/}
};

struct derived : base 
{
  void fn()
  {/*derived definition here*/}
};
```

In my actual program, these classes are passed as arguments to other classes and are called in other methods, but for the sake of simplicity let's create a simple function that takes as argument either the base or derived class. I can simply write

```
void call_fn(base& obj)
{obj.fn();}
```

and the call to the appropriate function will be resolved at **run-time** due to the virtual functions.

I am worried, however, that if the `call_fn`, is to be called million times (which in my case it will as my actual application is a simulation experiment), I will get a significant overhead which I would like to avoid.

So, I was wondering if using a static_cast could actually tackle the problem. Maybe something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void call_fn(base& obj)
{(static_cast<T*>(&obj))->fn();}
```

In this case, the function call would be done as `call_fn<base>(obj)` for calling the base method or `call_fn<derived>(obj)` for calling the derived method.

Will this solution avoid the vtable overhead or will it still be affected? Thanks in advance for any replies!

By the way, I am aware of the CRTP but not very familiar with it. That is why I would like to know the answer to this simple question first :)

Comment: What is your definition of *significant overhead*? You might be surprised as to what the overhead of calling a virtual function a few million times is.

Comment: Have you actually proven that vtable overhead is a problem with your code? And if so, can you show that doing the relevant "if (is this class) do this else do that" is faster? I suspect it isn't, unless it makes the compiler inline the function, and that saves a lot of effort.

Comment: I have not proven it...that is why I wanted to first create a method which avoids the vtable, so that I can compare the two and have a more clear idea of how significant that overhead may be :)

Comment: @linuxfever: The cost of dynamic dispatch is roughly the extra indirection. I.e. for a non-dynamic function call the compiler will inject a jump (`call`) to a fixed address. In the case of a virtual function it will perform an indirect call through the vtable. Many processors have specific instructions to calculate the address (`lea` and similar...). Unless your functions are basically empty the cost of the actual body of the function is going to drive the overall cost of the operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will this solution avoid the vtable overhead or will it still be affected?

It will still use dynamic dispatch (whether that causes any noticeable overhead is a completely different question). You can disable dynamic dispatch by qualifying the function call as in:

```
static_cast<T&>(obj).T::fn();
```

Although I would not even try to do so. Leave dynamic dispatch, then test the performance of the application, do some profiling, do further profiling. Profile again to make sure that you understand what the profiler is telling you. Only then, consider making a single change and profile again to verify whether your assumptions are correct or not.

Comment: +1 this is the answer. This is a valid technique IF you are completely sure that too much CPU is a small virtual function in a massive loop and you can't fix it properly. It's transforming `for (...) { (vtbl->foo)(); }` into `if (a) { for (...) A::foo(); } else { for (...) B::foo(); }`. Not likely to make much difference.

Comment: @linuxfever If it's not a tight loop around a 1 line or so virtual function, then vtbl call overhead will be negligible. Nice thing about tight loops is branch prediction works on indirect calls on modern (better than circa 1997 AMD K6) CPUs. Assuming your compiler isn't generating too much code working with argument passing, it will be fast. C++ uses vtbls because they are the fastest possible way to call something unknown.

Comment: @linuxfever On the other hand, the compiler might be able to hoist a ton of common subexpressions out of the loop if it inlines the direct (non-virtual) call.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really an answer to your actual question, but I was curious as to "what really is the overhead of calling a virtual function vs calling a regular class function". To make it "fair", I created a classes.cpp that implements a very simple function, but it's a in separate file that is compiled outside of the "main".

classes.h:

```
#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H

class base
{
    virtual int vfunc(int x) = 0;
};

class vclass : public base
{
public:
    int vfunc(int x);
};


class nvclass
{
public:
    int nvfunc(int x);
};


nvclass *nvfactory();
vclass* vfactory();


#endif
```

classes.cpp:

```
#include "classes.h"

int vclass:: vfunc(int x)
{
    return x+1;
}


int nvclass::nvfunc(int x)
{
    return x+1;
}

nvclass *nvfactory()
{
    return new nvclass;
}

vclass* vfactory()
{
    return new vclass;
}
```

This is called from:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "classes.h"

#if 0
#define ASSERT(x) do { if(!(x)) { assert_fail( __FILE__, __LINE__, #x); } } while(0)
static void assert_fail(const char* file, int line, const char *cond)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ASSERT failed at %s:%d condition: %s \n",  file, line, cond); 
    exit(1);
}
#else
#define ASSERT(x) (void)(x)
#endif

#define SIZE 10000000

static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}


void print_avg(const char *str, const int *diff, int size)
{
    int i;
    long sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    int t = diff[i];
    sum += t;
    }

    printf("%s average =%f clocks\n", str, (double)sum / size);
}


int diff[SIZE]; 

int main()
{
    unsigned long long a, b;
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    int x;

    vclass *v = vfactory();
    nvclass *nv = nvfactory();


    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
    a = rdtsc();

    x = 16;
    sum+=x;
    b = rdtsc();

    diff[i] = (int)(b - a);
    }

    print_avg("Emtpy", diff, SIZE);


    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
    a = rdtsc();

    x = 0;
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    x = v->vfunc(x);
    ASSERT(x == 4); 
    sum+=x;
    b = rdtsc();

    diff[i] = (int)(b - a);
    }

    print_avg("Virtual", diff, SIZE);

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
    a = rdtsc();
    x = 0;
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    x = nv->nvfunc(x);
    ASSERT(x == 4);     
    sum+=x;
    b = rdtsc();
    diff[i] = (int)(b - a);
    }
    print_avg("no virtual", diff, SIZE);

    printf("sum=%d\n", sum);

    delete v;
    delete nv;

    return 0;
}
```

The REAL difference in code is this:
virtual call:

```
40066b: ff 10                   callq  *(%rax)
```

non virtual call:

```
4006d3: e8 78 01 00 00          callq  400850 <_ZN7nvclass6nvfuncEi>
```

And the results:

```
Emtpy average =78.686081 clocks
Virtual average =144.732567 clocks
no virtual average =122.781466 clocks
sum=480000000
```

Remember that that's the overhead for 16 calls per loop, so the difference between calling a function and not calling a function is around 5 clock cycles per iteration [including adding up the results and other processing required], and the virtual call adds 22 clocks per iteration, so around 1.5 clocks per call.

**I doubt you will notice, assuming you do something a bit more meaningful than return x + 1 in your function.**

Comment: +1 Nice analysis, although you should include the lookup as well in your "REAL difference". If the two lines you have shown actually were the entire difference, the virtual implementation wouldn't be slower!

Comment: +1, also note that in real code, the function probably does more than a single addition, and the difference in calling will be much lower than the cost of the function.

Comment: The difference in the two lines is that one uses an indirect method of addressing `*(%rax)` and the other uses a direct address `400850`. If it's called more rarely than in a tight loop, then there's some more work to find the vtable and such, but then you also have more other code to worry about it's effect on calls.

Comment: What I really should add is a "if (a) use_cast_to_get_rid_of_volatile(virtual_a) else use_cast_to_get_rid_of_volatile(virtual_b);" and compare that to alternating calls to virtual_a and virtual_b.

Answer (score 0):

The VTable resides in your class.  If you have virtual members, they will be accessed through the VTable.  The cast will not affect whether or not the VTable exists, nor how members are accessed.

Comment: Not true. If the compiler knows the static type of the variable at run-time, it can call the function directly instead of going through the vtable. Virtual functions are only used with pointers and references.

Comment: @MarkRansom All calls to virtual functions go through the vtbl, no matter if the compiler "knows" the type. A global optimizer could optimize that scenario, but it wouldn't be likely to be THAT aggressive unless it is doing profile-guided optimizations. The key to gaining performance by bypassing vtbl calls is inlining. Unless the compiler is certain that most calls are to a certain type, it would probably just do an indirect call.

Comment: @doug65536, look at the generated assembler for a call to a virtual function on a local variable (not a pointer or reference) and tell me what you see. I'll agree that avoiding the vtable probably doesn't buy much.

Comment: @MarkRansom Typically if you have a virtual function you are using a base type pointer everywhere and it has to be virtual (base type has pure virtual declaration for that method). You are right though, the compiler can know the exact type, like a local variable of the real type.

Comment: And yes my original assertion of all calls being virtual was wrong. I confused what I typically do with what you can do.

Comment: What I should have said was, if you make a call to a method using a pointer, if that class any bases have a virtual method with the same signature then it will be a virtual call. If it is an instance call (not pointer) then it can directly call that types method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a polymorphic array, where the elements are polymorphic but all elements have the same type, you can also externalize the vtable. This allows you to look up the function once and then call it directly on each element. In that case, C++ doesn't help you though, you will have to do it manually.

This is also useful if you are microoptimizing things. I believe that Boost's function uses a similar technique. It only needs two functions (call and release reference) in the vtable, but the compiler-generated one would also contain RTTI and some other stuff, which can be avoided by hand-coding a vtable that only has those two function pointers.